# Using PostgreSQL row_to_json with jOOQ

Tags: postgresql, jooq

Is there anything more idiomatic than

```
    List<JSON> jsons = context.fetch("select row_to_json(p) j from persons p")
        .stream()
        .map(r -> r.get("j", JSON.class))
        .toList();
```

to use `row_to_json()` with jOOQ?

I tried using `function("row_to_json", ...)` but couldn't figure out how to fill the remaining arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of syntax (e.g. Oracle has `JSON_OBJECT(*)`) might be supported in the near future out of the box via [#10685](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/10685).

The [`DSL.function()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#function(java.lang.String,java.lang.Class,org.jooq.Field...)) method requires a `Field<?>...` list, so it cannot accept a table, currently. But you can use a [plain SQL template](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql-templating/) also for your function usage, without having to make the entire query a template, e.g. like this:

```java
static Field<JSON> rowToJson(Table<?> t) {
    return DSL.field("row_to_json({0})", SQLDataType.JSON, t);
}
```

And now use it like this:

```java
context.select(rowToJson(PERSONS)).from(PERSONS).fetch();
```